# Batch convert xls-Files to csv

Tags: excel, csv

I need to convert over 100 Excel files to CSV. Worse these files consist of multiple sheets and I only need one of them.

At first I stumbled upon the Perl program xls2csv. Luckily I even found on [XLS file conversion](http://www.topology.org/linux/xls.html) at the bottom a convenient script that converts all sheets into seperate csv files. But unluckily this converter is broken and skips lines.

I also tried [pyodconverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) but that only converts the first sheet.

Any suggestions? It would be ok if that conversion had to be done on Windows though I would really prefer Linux. And if it has to be Windows it would be nice if it wouldn't need an Excel installation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178218/r-linux-shell-convert-multi-sheet-xls-to-csv-in-batch

Answer (score 1):

There's a very useful java library called Apache POI at http://poi.apache.org/

The following link provides an example application that converts xls to csv.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java

If you know java you can adjust it to your needs. Since it's java it runs also on linux.

Comment: Looks as the way to go on Linux. Though this smells like I need Maven for this ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could also have a look at StatTransfer... (Win only, I'm afraid)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but there is actually an HTA (HTML Application) which can do this.  The details and download link can be found [here](http://cwestblog.com/2013/04/12/batch-excel-to-csv-converter-application/).