# R Linux Shell convert multi-sheet xls to csv in batch

Tags: r, bash, csv, xls

In R i have a script gets content of multiple xls files <[Loop over directory to get Excel content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130048/loop-over-directory-to-get-excel-content)>.

All files are about 2 MB. The script takes a few seconds for 3 files, but is now running for 6 hours on a Debian i7 system without results on 120 files.

A better solution is therefore [hopefully] to convert all xls files to csv using ssconvert, using a bash script <[Linux Shell Script For Each File in a Directory Grab the filename and execute a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297510/linux-shell-script-for-each-file-in-a-directory-grab-the-filename-and-execute-a)>:

```
for f in *.xls ; do xls2csv "$f" "${f%.xls}.csv" ; done
```

This script does the job, however my content is in sheet nr 14, whereas the csv files produced by this script just return the first sheet [i replaced 'xls2csv' with 'ssconvert'].

Can this script be adopted to pickup only sheet nr 14 in the workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the worksheet name, you can do this:

```
for f in *.xls ; xls2csv -x "$f" -w sheetName -c "${f%.xls}.csv";done
```

To see all the xls2csv  details see [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ken/xls2csv-1.06/script/xls2csv).

**EDIT**

The OP find the right answer, so I edit mine to add it :

```
for f in *.xls ; do xls2csv -x "$f" -f -n 14 -c "${f%.xls}.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy, will try this, but my worksheets sometimes have no value in the first column, in which case the script assumes the whole line to be empty.

Comment: @Henk I don't understand. looks like you talk about another problem. sometimes? how much? does the script resolve 80% of your problem. You can mix the methods, use the conversion to csv when it works otherwise readxls method.

Comment: agstudy, the 'caveats' section of the link to xls2csv says that 'A line in the spreadsheet is assumed to be blank if there is nothing in the first column.' Sometimes there is no value in column A, meaning that the script will skip the entire line - but i need the values of columns 12:14.

Comment: The 1.07 version of the Perl script contains a -f switch that forces everything to be parsed [avoid the empty row problem], but the script above has some problem: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `xls2csv'

Comment: solved : for f in *.xls ; do xls2csv -x "$f" -f -n 14 -c "${f%.xls}.csv" ; done

Answer (score 1):

For this job I use a python script named ssconverter.py (which you can find [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-spreadsheets-csv-files-python-and-pyuno-part-1v2), scroll down and download the two attachments, ssconverter.py and ooutils.py), which I call directly from R using `system()`.

It can extract a specific sheet in the workbook, not only by name but also by sheet number, for example:

```
ssconverter.py infile.xls:2 outfile.csv
```

to extract the second sheet.

You need to have python and python-uno installed.

Comment: This sounds excellent Theodore. How would you loop this over the 120 spreadsheets that I have?

Comment: +1! it looks promising ! to do this in  you can use something liek this , `ll <- list.files(patt='*.xls');
lapply(ll, function(x) system(paste('sconverter.py ',x,':2 ', gsub('(.*)[.]xls','\\1.csv',x),sep='')))`

Comment: Hi Theodore, it does not work somehow. Python and python3-uno installed. Produces: sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected.

Comment: How exactly did you try to run it? I find it strange that you get a syntax error from sh and not from the python interpreter; please paste the exact command you used. For me (debian sid) it works with python2.7 and python-uno, haven't tested with python3 and python3-uno. You need to have ssconverter.py and ooutils.py in the same directory, and usually I place them in the R working directory and loop with `lapply()` like agstudy showed.

Comment: here is the code: ll <- list.files(patt='*.xls')

lapply(ll, function(x) system(paste('sconverter.py ',x,':2 ', gsub('(.*)[.]xls','\\1.csv',x),sep=''))) - python-uno does not want to install, only python3-uno, maybe that is the problem.The .py files are in the same directory as the .R script and the .xls files.