# How to read a part of excel file into data frame r?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I need to read many .xlsx format files into data frame. Every excel file has the same format like
Date       GrossProfit NetProfit PnlLow
10/15/2013 3000        2500      -500
10/20/2013 3100        2600      -500
10/22/2013 -500        -600      -1000
Total      6100        5100

BestDay 2600
WorstDay -500

The last row of the table, which called total, doesn't have values for every column. There is other part below the table as you see and separated by a blank row.

How to read the table into data frame (best include the "Total" row)？ I tried read.table(file, nrow = 4, head = T, sep = ""); then warning message occurs: In read.table("Results2.xlsx", nrows = 5, header = T, sep = " ") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'Results2.xlsx'

Comment: `read.table` can only read text files (including .csv files). If you want to read Excel files you'll need to use one of the packages designed for that.

Comment: ...namely **XLConnect** or **xlsx**. There's also a perl based function in **gdata** I think. Just Googling "read excel file in r" will get you all of this information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178218/r-linux-shell-convert-multi-sheet-xls-to-csv-in-batch if your on linux to batch convert all your Excell files to csv

Answer (score 0):

If you have several files with consistent names, such as Results1.xlsx, Results2.xlsx, you may try:

```
setwd("path/to/your/file")
library(gdata)
for (i in 1:2) {
 filename = paste("Results", i, ".xlsx", sep = "")
 assign(paste("res", i, sep =""), read.xls(filename, 1))
}
```

assuming that the worksheet that you want to read is the first one. Otherwise just change the number, or give the name of the required worksheet.

Then you can manipulate the data frame to get the values that you need.

Comment: I read the documentation of read.xls. It seems that read.xls will not ignore the small part separated by a blank row from the table.

Comment: I have found .csv to be the most stable file to read into R.  It is best to use read.csv().  Either set your working director or use read.csv(file.choose()) to navigate your directory with the GUI.  As an FYI if you insert your table as code it will be much easier to read.

Comment: 1 simply means that this is the first worksheet on your Excel file. Even if there is a blank row after "Total", read.xls will read your table. It is not clear though what you would like to do with the tables once they are in R, so it's difficult to help.